# Updating mat-table on Angular

Tags: angular6

I need to update mat-table after inserting data on database.My form and mat table is in same page. From form i am inserting data to database. On database it insert successfully. but my mat-table does not update. If I refresh the page than mat-table will be updated. But i need to make mat-table update after inserting data to database.

### Spring Service

```
const: httpOptions = {
.......
}
export class SpringService {
  public getAllClubs(): any {
  return this.http.get(this.baseUrl+"/currentseason/get/clubs",httpOptions); 
  }
}
```

### AppComponent.ts

```
expport class AppComponent implements OnInit {
clubdetails = new MatTableDataSource();
displayedColumns: string[] = [.....];
  ngOnInt() {
   this.getClubList();
  }
  getClubList() {
  this.springService.getAllClubs().pipe(
  ........
  ).subscribe(res => {this.clubdetails.data= res;});
  }

}
```

### Appcomponent.html

```
<form (ngSubmit)="mymethod()">........</form>
<table mat-table [dataSource] = "clubdetails">
.............
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use BehaviorSubject<> object, with this you call the next function for update a subscription elements, for example:

```
@Component({selector:'my-component', templateUrl: './my-component.html', style:[]})
export class MyComponentComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private dataObj = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
  private dataSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, springService: SpringService){

    // Subscribe with BehaviorSubject
    this.dataSunscription= this.dataObj
                               .asObservable()
                               .subscribe(res => this.clubdetails.data= res);

    this.refreshData(); // fill with first data
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.dataSubscription.unsubscribe();
  } 

  // Refresh the data, and call the next function of BehaviorSubject
  refreshData(){
    this.springService.getAllClubs()
        .toPromise()
        .then( dt => this.dataObj.next(dt));        
  }

  mymethod(){
    // Call your code

    refreshData(); // Refresh after post the data
  }
}
```

you can see an example on [this page](https://blog.angulartraining.com/rxjs-subjects-a-tutorial-4dcce0e9637f)

Answer (score 0):

Just make these changes in `getClubList()` method:

```
  getClubList() {
    this.springService.getAllClubs().pipe(
      ........
    ).subscribe(res => {
        this.clubdetails.data = res;
        this.clubdetails.data = this.clubdetails.data;
      });
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

In your `app.component.ts` try following code,

```
 getClubList() {
  this.springService.getAllClubs().pipe(
  ........
  ).subscribe(res => {this.clubdetails.data= res;
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.Model_Obj_Name);});
  }
```